# Security issue was taking my visitors to a dangerous download page

Tags: javascript, android, wordpress, cordova, security

My website was suffering from a mysterious redirection to a suspicious download page. This was happening with all my visitors who's traffic source was the native facebook's android application. Clicking on my page's publications was, as usual, loading the website's shared link on the facebook's internal WebView but, without any consent of my own, and after the application loading process reached about 90% of the total pageload, the webview automatically triggered a external link opening my devices' default browser on the url that you see below.

As expected it was triggering a download request and asking me to accept the file to be downloaded which I of course denied.

Facts:

- No issues on android default browser using the website
- No issues on ios
- No issues on desktop chrome's
- Only saw the problem when using the facebook's app and opening the website on - it's internal webview

The URL was the following. For safety I added the **_ to the url.

**http**://traf___fic2015.ru/fr2/Mise_a_jour_Android_6.apk**

Is there something I can do to find the source of the problem? I can't reproduce it anymore and I'm concerned about my visitors' safety.

PS: I also tried to load website from from a Phonegap/Cordova Webview but the problem seems to have disappeared without doing anything.

**Could it be comming from facebook?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes it could becoming from facebook as they are not immune to hacks.